# how remove break line with awk or sed?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, terminal

I'm trying to remove the line break from a csv file

```
1 2010-01-08|2010|00360| PAPELETAS DE TRÁNSITO|.000|13.680
2 2010-01-08|2010|00367|30%) DEL ÁREA TOTAL DEL <--here
 LOCAL, MÓDULOS, STANS|.000|36.000
3 2010-01-08|2010|00384|EXTERIOR (VÍA PÚBLICA)/DERECHO DE TRAMITACIÓN|.000|6.840
```

my csv has 6 columns separated by "|" and I want to do a single line, but when exporting from the database I have a line break in row 2

Comment: What do you use to determine the location of the line break that you want to omit?  Is it merely the fact that the following line does not match `[0-9]{4}-[0-2]{2}-[0-9]{2}`, or is there some other criteria.  Make it precise, and the problem is pretty simple.

Comment: Your script is checking for double quotes (`"`) but there are no double quotes in your example. Are there double quotes in your real data? If so, edit your example to show where they occur (probably around fields and maybe also escaped mid-field). Can you have `|`s in the middle of a field (presumably escaped in some way)? If so edit your example to show that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F \| '{c+=NF}c<6{ORS=""}c>=6{ORS=RS;c=0}1' file
```

would do assuming that your `|` separated file contains 6 columns in a record.

Comment: @BrayanPastor Most welcome, I have changed the solution to  fit multiple breaks which I guess ian alternative for \@william-pursell's solution covering multiple breaks mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55816079/1620779).

Answer (score 2):

Making a lot of assumptions, you might just want:

```
awk 'NF==6{ print; next}  {getline x; $0 = $0 x } 1' FS=\| input
```

which can be simplified a bit to:

```
awk 'NF < 6 {getline x; $0 = $0 x } 1' FS=\| input
```

Or (if you may want to join more than 2 consecutive lines)

```
awk '{while(NF < 6) {getline x; $0 = $0 x }} 1' FS=\| input
```

These are both pretty fragile solutions.  Reader be warned.

Comment: the `more than 2 consecutive` lines solution makes  the solution complete. :-)

Comment: If getline fails (e.g. if there are less than 6 fields at the end of the file) then that will quietly print duplicates of the fields it did read. You should really use `if ( (getline x) > 0 ) $0 = $0 x` instead of just `getline x; $0 = $0 x` to handle the rainy day case better. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. Of course if fields are really double-quote enclosed as I suspect they are and they can then contain `|`s then it's time for something completely different (attr: Monty Python :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

if the data in 'd' file, tried on gnu sed,

in terms of line number

```
sed '2{N;s/\n//}' d
```

in terms of pattern

```
sed -E '/^([0-9][^|]+\|){3,}\S+(\s+[A-Za-z/(.,)]+)+/{N;s/\n//}' d
```

Comment: You may need to modify the answer to fit in multiple line-breaks